# Nlog Http target with FallbackGroup wrapper not working as expected

Tags: nlog

How do I handle failures if Nlog Http target fails? I tried to use FallbackGroup wrapper with Http as a first target and file as a second target. It is not working as expected. I see logs are going on both targets if first target is working. If first target HTTP is not running then my application does not work. Here is my nlog.config looks like

```
<target xsi:type="FallbackGroup" name="fallBackElkToFile" returnToFirstOnSuccess="true">
            <target xsi:type='Http' 
                    BatchSize='1'
                    IgnoreSslErrors='true' 
                                        URL='${Api.URL}' 
                            Authorization='${Api.Authorization}'
                            ContentType='application/json'>
                <layout xsi:type="EcsLayout" includeAllProperties="true"/>
            </target>
            <target xsi:type="File" name="file"                                fileName="${logsDir}\${shortdate}.log">
                <layout xsi:type="EcsLayout" includeAllProperties="true"/>
            </target>
        </target>
```

Comment: You can try and cheer for https://github.com/DarekDan/NLog.Targets.HTTP/pull/47 as it should make the batching work together with [NLog FallbackGroup](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FallbackGroup-target).

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks for your comment. I tried it and it is still not working when Http timeout.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this. Have created https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/5193 for NLog v5.1.4

Comment: NLog v5.1.4 has been released - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/5.1.4 where `AsyncTaskTarget` will work together with `FallbackGroup`